# Clean way to unescape a single unicode char in python json.dumps(array)?

Tags: python, json, string, unicode, escaping

I need to send some data to a server that I do not own or operate. The data must be sent in a form parameter via HTTP POST. The key must be "logs" and the value must be a JSON array. Each element of this array is a CSV string, delimited by *the unicode representation* of `Ctrl-A`, `\u0001` (*not* the literal char).

When I convert my array of CSV strings to a JSON array, via `json.dumps`, it implicitly escapes some characters (such as `"`).

**Problem:** `json.dumps` also implicitly escapes my CSV delimiter `\u0001`, changing it to `\\u0001`, which causes the server to reject my data. To work-around this, I manually "un"-escape it: `s.replace('\\\\u0001', '\\u0001')`

**Question:** Are there any potential repercussions to using this hacky workaround? Is there a more elegant way for me to handle this problem?

```
# Ctrl-A (\u0001) delimited CSV strings
logs = ['VAL1\\u0001{"key":"VAL2"}', 'VAL1\\u0001{"key":"VAL2"}'] 

# Serialize as JSON (it implicitly escapes chars, including Ctrl-A)
serialized_logs = json.dumps(logs)

# replace '\\u0001' with '\u0001' (unescape it)
# this seems HACKY -- is there a better way to handle this?
serialized_logs = serialized_logs.replace('\\\\u0001', '\\u0001')

# send over HTTP
params = { 'logs' : serialized_logs }
response = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

Note: python 2.7

Comment: I dont understand why you dont just send the normal byte... why does it have to be escaped?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Hi again Joran, thanks for coming back. I am wondering that very same thing. This is a requirement imposed by the service, and I have no control over this. I agree, it is strange.

Comment: https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/SoreGrimQuotient looks like it is still escaped here ... with only one ... did you delete your other question?

Comment: I suspect you are misinterpreting the services documentation ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley The backslash is escaped though. The chars that I want to be sent over HTTP is `\u0001`, not `\\u0001`

Comment: then dont escape it when you make the original strings?

Comment: @JoranBeasley This will cause the literal Ctrl-A to be sent. The server rejects the literal char. It wants the unicode representation. It is strange, but this is the behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183752/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-james-wierzba).

Answer (score 0):

just use unicode strings in your list and dont escape the unicode

```
logs2 = [u'VAL1\u0001{"key":"VAL2"}', u'VAL1\u0001{"key":"VAL2"}'] 
serialized_logs2 = json.dumps(logs2)
```

should do the right thing you can verify it by

```
print(serialized_logs2 == serialized_logs.replace("\\\\u0001","\\u0001"))
```

(where serialized_logs is your `json.dumps` result above)

see: https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/SoreGrimQuotient  (python2)

Comment: What is the difference between `u"\u0001"` and `"\\u0001"`?

Comment: oh wait are you in python3 ... in python3 you dont need the u escape... `u"s"` just makes sure its a unicode string ... "s" is just a bytestring (in python3 that changes)

Comment: I'm in python 2, sorry I should have specified